# Is the statement "Leah had weak eyes" (Genesis 29:17) an indication that women at that time had their face covered where only their eyes showed?

Tags: genesis, cultural-analysis

In Genesis 2k9:17 the only specific part of the body mentioned is the eyes.  Is this because everything else was covered up?

> “Leah was tender eyed; but Rachel was beautiful and well favoured” (KJV). The tender eyes of Leah, as so translated in the KJV, were actually eyes that were visually weak or lacked luster—dull and unimpressive eyes. This was considered to be a great defect among those who admired sparkling eyes that were lively and flashing. That Leah’s eyes were compared to Rachel’s beauty obviously meant there was no beauty in them and that Leah herself was probably plain in face and form compared to her sister.
> --
> Freeman, J. M., & Chadwick, H. J. (1998). *Manners & customs of the Bible* (p. 55). Bridge-Logos Publishers.

> For the elder daughter, Leah, had weak eyes, and consequently was not so good-looking; since bright eyes, with fire in them, are regarded as the height of beauty in Oriental women.
> --
> Keil, C. F., & Delitzsch, F. (1996). *Commentary on the Old Testament* (Vol. 1, p. 183). Hendrickson.

Answer (score 6):

The Hebrew word "רַכּ֑וֹת" which the KJV translates as "tender" in Genesis 29:17, actually has a broad sense of meaning, ranging from soft and tender to timid and weak.  In Leah's case, it most likely implies that she was soft-spoken, or timid.  While one might imagine a timid person being more inclined to cover up, as if to hide, there is nothing in the text to suggest that this was the case with Leah.  In fact, the passage does not even mention a veil at all, nor is there any suggestion that either Rachel or Leah had ever covered herself in such a manner.

The Hebrew word is also used for young and "tender" children (see Genesis 33:13), for "fainthearted" men (see Deuteronomy 20:8), for a "tender" man (see Deuteronomy 28:54), and for a "weak" King David (see 2 Samuel 3:39).  It is unlikely that any of these would have been covered up with a veil.

Answer (score 3):

There is no indication that the rest of Leah's face and was covered up. This may have been the case on the night she was presented to Jacob so that he would not recognize her, but not normally. Certainly the eyes were important, but the complete verse mentioned in the OP states: "Leah’s eyes were weak, but Rachel was beautiful and lovely." It is unlikely that the author referred only to Rachel's eyes here. Leah's eyes are singled out as a defect - an explanation for why Jacob preferred Rachel.

Not much is know about veiling traditions in the time of Abraham, but during the Assyrian Empire (roughly the same geographical area about 500 years later) [veils were required for upper class women](https://www.ancient-origins.net/history-ancient-traditions/veil-wearing-tradition-0017535). On the other hand, veils were actually forbidden to slaves and prostitutes, so whatever we can derive from this regulation, it does not apply to women generally.

Moreover, even wealthy women, would probably veil themselves only in public, not in a family setting, especially in a rural environment where public encounters were rare.  Also, wearing a veil while tending flocks and watering them, as both Rachel and Leah did, would not be practical.

**To conclude: the reference to Leah having weak eyes is not an indication that women at the time would not show their faces.**

Comment: A supplementary point which supports your case; Rebekah covered herself only when she saw Isaac (Genesis ch24 v65). The implication is that only married women veiled themselves, and she considered herself a married woman from that moment. The convention seems to have survived into the old European traditions of veiled nuns and brides.

Comment: In Rebekah's case we should also consider that she was already betrothed to Isaac perhaps indicating the custom that we know from later Jewish tradition that brides should veil themselves from their husbands on their wedding day. She did not veil herself from Isaac's servant or others in the caravan (10 camels plus any men who tended them) on the road.

Comment: @ Dan fefferman I've always been fond of the romantic interpretation, that she fell in love with him at first sight and decided not to wait for any formal ceremony before considering herself a wife needing to hide her face from other men.  "Yeah, THAT's my husband!"  Not dramatic, just a quiet gesture.